# A record should be hostname or ip address

Tags: ip-address, nameservers

I got an email from my hosting provider (bluehost in this case) that name of the server should be vps.sitename.com ]
After updating the hostname you should add an A record for the entry vps.sitename.com in the registered nameservers of sitename.com

So my question is what should be A record pointing to?

```
@ ip address or 

@ vps.sitename.com
```

Comment: I think this is not the right place for this question.

Comment: The A record should contain vps.sitename.com and its corresponding ip address. If if it is just for a single machine just use your host file.

Comment: @Tarik - It is for domain by godaddy. So i should use two @ signs with vps.sitename.com in one and ip address in other? Can you put that in answer how it should be?

Answer (score 1):

A Record is a 'Address Record' and point to where your website is located, a physical address. it should be an IP address.